# vary box height based on the text length inside

Tags: html, css

I would like to wrap the content of varying length text within a box. With the below code, the width of the box is adjusted for smaller length text. But the height doesn't vary and text is not wrapped inside the box.

```css
.chatbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3.5em/5em;
  padding: 2%;
  max-width: 60%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed justo arcu, aliquet quis interdum sed, molestie iaculis turpis. Morbi rutrum molestie mauris id gravida. Curabitur libero tortor, tincidunt at facilisis vitae, euismod id urna. Proin sit amet
  facilisis est. Vivamus id rutrum eros, in tempus mauris. Nunc nec velit tempus, varius neque sit amet, varius mi. Nullam ullamcorper lacus arcu, eu commodo magna consectetur sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 .chatbox{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3.5em/5em;
    padding:2em;
    max-width:60%;
    float:left;
 }
```

You don't need `height:auto` and `word-wrap`, which create the problem. I changed the `padding` to be compatible with `border-radius`.

Answer (score 2):

Change `white-space:nowrap` to `white-space:normal` , hope this will help you

```css
.chatbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3.5em/5em;
  padding: 2%;
  max-width: 60%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed justo arcu, aliquet quis interdum sed, molestie iaculis turpis. Morbi rutrum molestie mauris id gravida. Curabitur libero tortor, tincidunt at facilisis vitae, euismod id urna. Proin sit amet
  facilisis est. Vivamus id rutrum eros, in tempus mauris. Nunc nec velit tempus, varius neque sit amet, varius mi. Nullam ullamcorper lacus arcu, eu commodo magna consectetur sit amet.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace your css with below css:

```
.chatbox{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:3.5em/5em;
    padding:2%;
    max-width:60%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;

    word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

Comment: There is no need of `word-wrap` property as there is no such long length word in OP's code.

Comment: yes actually he just need to remove  white-space: nowrap; from his css

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `white-space: nowrap` it works this way.

```
 .chatbox{
        border:1px solid black;
        border-radius:3.5em/5em;
        padding:2%;
        max-width:60%;
        height:auto;
        float: left;
    }
```